# возвращать два последующих элемента массива. Если нет, начинать заново

Tags: javascript

Есть массив элементов

```
const arrsy =   [
  {
    background: 'blue'
  },
  {
    background: 'lightblue'
  },
  {
     background: 'red'
  },
  {
    background: 'lightpink'
  },
]
```

нужно написать функцию, которая возвращает два последующих элемента. Если их нет, то начинаем сначала.

Например:

Выбираем нулевой элемент - возвращается первый и второй. Выбираем второй - возвращается третий и нулевой (так как четвертого уже нет).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
const arrsy = [ 
  {
    background: 'blue'
  },
  {
    background: 'lightblue'
  },
  {
     background: 'red'
  },
  {
    background: 'lightpink'
  },
];

function nextTwo(i) {
  return [
    arrsy[i = (i + 1) % arrsy.length],
    arrsy[i = (i + 1) % arrsy.length]
  ];
}

console.log(nextTwo(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю один из вариантов, как-то так:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    background: "blue"
  },
  {
    background: "lightblue"
  },
  {
    background: "red"
  },
  {
    background: "lightpink"
  }
];

function getNext(elem, arr) {
  const result = [];
  const findedIndex = arr.findIndex(
    item => item.background === elem.background
  );
  let nextIndex = findedIndex;
  for (let counter = 1; counter <= 2; counter++) {
    nextIndex += 1;
    if (nextIndex === arr.length) {
        nextIndex = 0;
    }
    result.push(arr[nextIndex]);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(
    getNext({ background: "red" }, arr)
);
```